# Template class with specific array dimensionality

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, types

I'm basically trying to make a `Container` class that works with an already predefined `Data` class. What I am trying to achieve is for the class to be initialized with different number of pointers (dimensionality) depending on the template I pass (shown below). The key here is the `Data` class is external, I cannot alter it.

```cpp
// this is just for the demo (I cannot change this class, it's from an external library):
template<class T>
class Data {
  T m_data;
};

enum Dimension { ONE_D, TWO_D, THREE_D };

// this is the class I'm trying to make:
template<class T, Dimension D>
class Container {
  Data<T*> data; // <- for ONE_D
  Data<T**> data; // <- for TWO_D
  Data<T***> data; // <- for THREE_D
};

// desired example usage
Container<float, ONE_D> mycontainer;
```

I have been kind of able to achieve this in a pretty ugly way:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ONE_D {
  using ndtype_t = T*;
};

template <typename T>
struct TWO_D {
  using ndtype_t = T**;
};

template <typename T>
struct THREE_D {
  using ndtype_t = T***;
};

template <class U, template <typename T> class D>
class Container {
  Data<typename D<U>::ndtype_t> data;
};


Container<float, ONE_D> mycontainer;
```

But I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me this smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and generalization taken too far. Why do you need one single class to be able to handle all three cases? What are the use-cases for this container? What is the underlying problem it's supposed to solve, that you can't solve with plain array of arrays or vectors of vectors?

Comment: It might indeed be the XY, but unlikely, since I've given this a lot of thought. In short, this `Data` class is an array-type object with overloaded indexing operators `(i,j,k)` that can be compiled both on GPU and CPU and exploit the `simd` processing on various microarchitectures. The neat thing about it is it handles all the differences in architectures (avx2 vs avx512, looping via caching vs coalescing, parallelizing etc) internally, which is crucial if you're spending 1e6 CPU-hrs multiplying arrays and matrices.

Comment: The reason I need a single container class is I will have methods that are common for all of the dimensions: read from/write to file, scalar multiply `Data A` by `Data B` etc. Now in principle I could have `Container2D`, `Container3D` etc, but then I'd have to rewrite all these routines for each of the classes.

Comment: Inheritance where you put common code in the base class? Also, trying to cram everything into a single class will very likely make the code harder to maintain.

Comment: Why multi-D array uses pointer-to-pointer? That smells of ragged array, which in some cases is worst implementation pecause of locality issues?

Comment: It's actually not a ragged array in its core. This datatype internally decides the most efficient way of laying out the data in memory depending on the architecture you compile it on (x86 cpus, knls, arms, gpus etc).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was a little unconventional, but I think it's a neater solution than what I had earlier.

```cpp
template <typename T, Dimension D>
using RealND = typename std::conditional<D == ONE_D,
                      T*,
                  typename std::conditional<D == TWO_D,
                      T**,
                  typename std::conditional<D == THREE_D,
                      T***,
                    std::nullptr_t>::type>::type>::type;

template<class T, Dimension D>
class Container {
  Data<RealND<T,D>> data;
};
```